# How can a YouTube video has more likes than views?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

See this screenshot of the YouTube video:

[image]

It has more likes than views. Youtubers making comments like YouTube drinking again etc.

How can a YouTube video has more likes than views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likes are updated in real time. Views are not:

> We want to make sure that videos are being viewed by actual humans and not computer programs. During the first couple of hours after a video has been published, we'll only show views that our systems believe to be valid. This might not yet show all legitimate views at that time.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en